# How to call mongoDB userdefined functions in JAVA(Spring boot) project

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a functions :

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "myFunction",
    value: function (x) {
        return  db.table2.find().toArray();
    }
});
```

How to execute in java code...As i know MongoClient eval() is deprecated. But is there any other way to execute such functions.
The only reason I want to use functions to be used as StoredProcedure.

Answer (score 0):

Eval operations are now deprecated. JS execution on server is the only way to achieve what you need like batch process. So you switch to [java mongoDB driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) instead of writing store procedure.